# BigQuery join broadcast limit error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a query similar to this:

```
SELECT date, group, COUNT(a.user_id) as count
FROM (
SELECT user_id, DATE(timestamp) as date
FROM [db.log_2015_08]
GROUP EACH BY user_id, date) as a
JOIN EACH (
SELECT user_id, group
FROM [db.users]) as b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY date, group
```

And getting the following error:

```
Error: Shuffle reached broadcast limit for table __I0 (broadcasted at least 137619698 bytes). Consider using partitioned joins instead of broadcast joins .
```

I've been using BigQuery for a while, and this is a new one for me! It is a pretty big join, but I feel like I've done similar before without this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `GROUP EACH BY` to `GROUP BY`. The `EACH` keyword is no longer needed for aggregations, and in fact the query planner can be a little smarter if you drop it.